# Print the actual query MySQLdb runs?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm looking for a way to debug queries as they are executed and I was wondering if there is a way to have MySQLdb print out the actual query that it runs, after it has finished inserting the parameters and all that?  From the documentation, it seems as if there is supposed to be a Cursor.info() call that will give information about the last query run, but this does not exist on my version (1.2.2).

This seems like an obvious question, but for all my searching I haven't been able to find the answer.

Comment: Don't know this library, but if it uses actual MySQL's prepared statements, then the actual query will look like `EXECUTE stmt USING @var1, var2,....`. Not sure if it would be helpful for you.

Comment: I would just turn on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and then see what query gets executed.

Comment: @MichaelMior this isn't always an option, especially with hosted MySQL like Amazon's RDS.  It is useful to have python side access to it.  (Just wanted to point out that it's not always feasible to turn change mysql log settings.)

Comment: @TravisLeleu I'm sure there are some scenarios where this is true, but you can get access to the general log on RDS. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Answer (score 133, accepted):

We found an attribute on the cursor object called `cursor._last_executed` that holds the last query string to run even when an exception occurs.  This was easier and better for us in production than using profiling all the time or MySQL query logging as both of those have a performance impact and involve more code or more correlating separate log files, etc.

Hate to answer my own question but this is working better for us.

Answer (score 45):

### pymysql >= 1.0.3

According to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html)

```
cursor.statment
```

> This read-only property returns the last executed statement as a string. The statement property can be useful for debugging and displaying what was sent to the MySQL server.
>
> The string can contain multiple statements if a multiple-statement string was executed. This occurs for execute() with multi=True. In this case, the statement property contains the entire statement string and the execute() call returns an iterator that can be used to process results from the individual statements. The statement property for this iterator shows statement strings for the individual statements.

### pymysql < 1.0.3

You can print the last executed query with the cursor attribute `_last_executed`:

```
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, (arg1, arg2))
    connection.commit()
except:
    print(cursor._last_executed)
    raise
```

Currently, there is a discussion how to get this as a real feature in pymysql (see [pymysql issue #330: Add mogrify to Cursor, which returns the exact string to be executed](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/pull/330); `pymysql` should be used instead of `MySQLdb`)

edit: I didn't test it by now, but [this commit](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/commit/0f3f47333cf6a99f2ff1d6fd91457bbfcf8a605e) indicates that the following code might work:

```
cursor.mogrify(sql, (arg1, arg2))
```

Comment: pymysql now supports cur.mogrify(qstr, qargs)

Comment: Cursor._last_executed has indeed been removed from PyMySQL 1.0.3

Answer (score 44):

For me / for now `_last_executed` doesn't work anymore. In the current version you want to access

`cursor.statement`.

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html

Comment: Yes - 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed'

Comment: This will fail if your query raised an exception

Answer (score 16):

For mysql.connector:

```
cursor.statement
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html

Answer (score 12):

`cursor.statement` and `cursor._last_executed` raised `AttributeError` exception

```
cursor._executed
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

One way to do it is to turn on [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html):

```
cursor.execute('set profiling = 1')
try:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM blah where foo = %s',[11])
except Exception:
    cursor.execute('show profiles')
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)        
cursor.execute('set profiling = 0')
```

yields

```
(1L, 0.000154, 'SELECT * FROM blah where foo = 11')
```

Notice the argument(s) were inserted into the query, and that the query was logged even though the query failed.

Another way is to start the server with logging turned on:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d mysql stop
sudo mysqld --log=/tmp/myquery.log
```

Then you have to sift through /tmp/myquery.log to find out what the server received.

Answer (score 2):

I've had luck with `cursor._last_executed` generally speaking, but it doesn't work correctly when used with `cursor.executemany()`.  That drops all but the last statement. Here's basically what I use now in that instance instead (based on tweaks from the actual MySQLDb cursor source):

```
def toSqlResolvedList( cursor, sql, dynamicValues ):
    sqlList=[]
    try:
        db = cursor._get_db()
        if isinstance( sql, unicode ): 
            sql = sql.encode( db.character_set_name() )
        for values in dynamicValues :
            sqlList.append( sql % db.literal( values ) )
    except: pass
    return sqlList
```

Answer (score 0):

> This read-only property returns the last executed statement as a string. The statement property can be useful for debugging and displaying what was sent to the MySQL server.
> The string can contain multiple statements if a multiple-statement string was executed. This occurs for execute() with multi=True. In this case, the statement property contains the entire statement string and the execute() call returns an iterator that can be used to process results from the individual statements. The statement property for this iterator shows statement strings for the individual statements.

`str = cursor.statement`

source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html

Answer (score -1):

I can't say I've ever seen

```
Cursor.info()
```

In the documentation, and I can't find it after a few minutes searching.  Maybe you saw some old documentation?

In the mean time you can always turn on [MySQL Query Logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and have a look at the server's log files.

Comment: I saw it here http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html under "Cursor Objects": "info()
Returns some information about the last query. Normally you don't need to check this."

Answer (score -2):

assume that your sql is like `select * from table1 where 'name' = %s`

```
from _mysql import escape
from MySQLdb.converters import conversions

actual_query = sql % tuple((escape(item, conversions) for item in parameters))
```