# How to check and perform SQL statements in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am using the MySQLdb in Python. I was told that to properly create SQL statements and to avoid SQL injection attacks I should code something like:

```
sql = "insert into table VALUES ( %s, %s, %s )"
args = var1, var2, var3
cursor.execute( sql, args )
```

Or:

```
cursor.execute( "insert into table VALUES ( %s, %s, %s )", var1, var2, var3 )
```

Or even this (this might be wrong):

```
header = ( 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name' )
values = ( '12', 'bob'       , 'smith'     )
cursor.execute( "insert into table ( %s ) values ( %s )", ( header + values ) )
```

When I programmed in PHP, I would normally store my entire SQL statement as a long string then execute the string. Something like (with PostgreSQL):

```
$id         = db_prep_string( pg_escape_string( $id         ) );
$first_name = db_prep_string( pg_escape_string( $first_name ) );
$last_name  = db_prep_string( pg_escape_string( $last_name  ) );

$query = "insert into table ( id, first_name, last_name ) values ( $id, $first_name, $last_name )"

$result = pg_query( $con, $query );
$retval = pg_fetch_array( $result );
```

where `db_prep_string` is

```
function db_prep_string( $value ) {
    if( 
        !isset( $value ) ||
        (is_null($value)) ||
        preg_match( '/^\s+$/', $value ) ||
        ( $value == '' )
     ) {
    $value = 'null';
}
else {
    $value = "'$value'";
}
    return $value;
}
```

Then to debug, I could simply echo out `$query` to view the entire SQL statement. Is there something similar I can do with Python? In other words, can I store the **safe** SQL statement as a string, print it to debug, then execute it?

I would like to do something like:

```
id         = prevent_sql_injection_string( id         )
first_name = prevent_sql_injection_string( first_name )
last_name  = prevent_sql_injection_string( last_name  )

sql  = "insert into table ( id, first_name, last_name ) values "
sql += id         + ", "
sql += first_name + ", "
sql += last_name

print sql #for debugging

cursor.execute( sql )
```

If not, then how do I *view* the SQL statement in its entirety in Python?

Bonus question: how do I enter null values in a SQL statement using Python?

Comment: This is called using a "parameterized" query or SQL.

Comment: If you want to enter a null value, use `None`.

Comment: You embedded arguments in pgsql queries to get one huge string? Yuck! Even in PHP you have `pg_query_params` where you can separate the query from the values.

Comment: I originally thought that I liked storing a SQL query as a long string so I can take that string and manually enter it as a command on mysql. After reading some of the comments and answers, it seems like I should be using parameterized queries with tuples and , symbol (excuse my vague descriptions). I don't mind doing that but then what is the best practice to debug the SQL query?

Comment: The `_last_executed` cursor property looks promising, as mentioned in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7190914/4970

Comment: @JamesMurty Cool! `cur._last_executed` seems very useful! I put it inside a `try` `except` block and it at least shows me how I am entering the wrong SQL query. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Python Database API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) as it answers some of your questions. For example, on NULL values the API specification says this:

> SQL NULL values are represented by the Python None singleton on
>       input and output.

and on parameter styles the specification offers multiple options to the implementer, including the `'format'` option that MySQLdb uses.

If you want to see what query MySQLdb will execute against your database you can cheat a little and use the connections `literal(...)` method. For example:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(...)
>>> print "insert into table VALUES ( %s, %s, %s )" % db.literal((5, "ab'c", None))
insert into table VALUES ( 5, 'ab\\'c', NULL )
```

However the `db.literal(...)` method isn't really meant to be used by clients of the MySQLdb module, so don't put it in production code.

Also, note that the [MySQLdb documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysqldb) has this to say about parameters:

> Parameter placeholders can only be used to insert column values. They can not be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names, statements, etc.

So beware of using the parameter placeholders for the column names of a table in an insert statement.

Answer (score -3):

The code that you would like to do is valid. You can do something like:

```
def prevent_sql_injection_string( value ):
    if (value is None or str(value).strip()=''):
        value = 'null'
    else:
        value = "'%s'" % str(value)
    return value    

# convert inputs
id         = prevent_sql_injection_string( id         )
first_name = prevent_sql_injection_string( first_name )
last_name  = prevent_sql_injection_string( last_name  )

# construct query
# Note: "some formatted string" % (value,value,value) syntax is like doing
# printf("some formatted string",value,value,value)
sql = "insert into table (id, first_name, last_name ) values (%s, %s, %s)" 
         % (id,first_name,last_name)

# print
print sql

# execute
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Nobody should do that though!

Comment: Your code formatting seems wrong (no indented block after the first line that ends with `:`). Also, I don't see how this prevents anything. What if the string I'm protecting has a single quote in it? All you're doing is adding single quotes, so if my value is `"'; drop table foo"`, won't that cause problems?

Comment: Please explain why not if you're going to downvote - I am curious and would honestly like to know.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley, forgot about the extra line in there - fixed (and I just translated OP's code to Python - does PHP `pg_escape_string` guard against the `"';drop table foo"` sort of thing either?)