# Insert Data with pymysql using inputs

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm working on a DB and I'm having trouble when using pymysql to INSERT some values

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO orders (name, size, type, is_done) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""" 
% (name, size, type, is_done))
```

Where *name, size* and *type* are strings and *is_done* is a bool

It gives me the typical error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`, so I suppose the problem is a `'`, but how can I solve it?

**Edit**

I should also add that the name value is retrieved from a MySQL DB

Comment: check which query is really executed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071166/print-the-actual-query-mysqldb-runs  I think this link can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen that the command really is executed, so it's a dead end...

Comment: so, could you show excuted query?

Comment: @huhushow I have alredy found the problem, thanks for all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current accepted solution has a [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) vulnerability. You are not supposed to format the string with the `%` operator - just pass the tuple of arguments as a second argument, and the library will deal with the rest.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO orders (name, size, type, is_done) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
    (name, size, type, is_done))
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647301/how-do-pymysql-prevent-user-from-sql-injection-attack/51657742#51657742) and [pymysql documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, which was that instead of

```
  cur.execute("""INSERT INTO orders (name, size, type, is_done) 
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""" 
  % (name, size, type, is_done))
```

I should have done

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO orders (name, size, type, is_done) 
 VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")""" 
% (name, size, type, is_done))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't input value for id. You have an error. Try this query.

```
cur.execute("insert into orders values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (None, name, size, type, is_done))
```

"%s" and "None" for id column. This query running my code. 
Note: Don't forget commit()