# Parametric query when using 'load data infile'

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I use parametric queries for normal insert/updates for security.
How do I do that for queries like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/filepath' INTO TABLE mytable
```

In my case, the path to the file would be different everytime (for different requests). Is it fine to proceed like this (since I am not getting any data from outside, the file is from the server itself):

```
 path = /filepath
 "LOAD DATA INFILE" + path + "INTO TABLE mytable"
```

Comment: Are you asking for a permission?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for replying, Sir. I have all the permissions. As everything is done internally, I thought I could format the query using string concatenation, and do away with parametric queries like for inserts/updates. Just wanted to confirm the same.

Comment: But why? Because `LOAD DATA` is not allowed in prepared statements?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Am using Python MySQLdb for this.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Why don't you use "parametric queries" like you do for inserts and updates?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `1.`I was wondering that if I do not get any data to insert from outside, would I still need to be cautious about sql injection. 
`2.` I have no idea about how to write a parametric query for this.

Comment: It wouldn't be different as for INSERT or UPDATE - You replace the string (path) with a placeholder: `LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE mytable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LOAD DATA` is not listed in [SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) you can't prepare something like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE mytable
```

But `SET` is listed. So a workaround could be to prepare and execute

```
SET @filepath = ?
```

And then execute

```
LOAD DATA INFILE @filepath INTO TABLE mytable
```

#### Update

In Python with MySQLdb the following query should work

```
LOAD DATA INFILE %s INTO TABLE mytable
```

since no prepared statement is used.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about "prepared" statements, but rather "parameterized" statements which are handled client-side. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020100/10682164) answer which suggests prepared statements aren't even possible with MySQLdb.

Comment: @totalhack - If no prepared statements are used, then I see no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your "is it fine to proceed like this" question, your example code will fail because the resulting query will be missing quotes around the filename. If you changed it to the following it could run, but is still a bad idea IMO:

```
 path = "/filepath"
 sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + path + "' INTO TABLE mytable" # note the single quotes
```

While you may not be accepting outside input today, code has a way of sticking around and getting reused/copied, so you should use the API in a way that will escape your parameters:

```
sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE %s INTO TABLE mytable"
cursor.execute(sql, (path,))
```

And don't forget to commit if autocommit is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir, for clearing doubts about using string concatenation. Sticking to your advice, would opt for parametric query in this case too. That autocommit  remark should be in bold .