# Query parameterization in PyMySQL for query with "IN" keyword

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection, pymysql

I have a table which looks like

```
mysql> select * from statements;
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
| id | account_number | amount | type    |
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
|  1 |              1 |   1000 | Deposit |
|  2 |              1 |    500 | Fees    |
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a PyMySQL connector through which I want to execute a query `select * from statements where type in ('Deposit', 'Fees')`

My question is different from possible duplicates as it asks particularly for "IN" type of queries, where list sizes can be dynamic and are slightly difficult to write than the usual `%s` hardcoded `select * from statements where type in (%s, %s)` type of queries.

I am wondering how to exactly write the query in a way that it is parameterized and *relatively* safe from SQL injection. My current code snippet is as follows:

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect('''SQL DB credentials''')
cur = connection.cursor()
l = ['Deposit', 'Fees']
st = f'select * from statements where type in (' + ','.join(['%s'] * len(l)) + ')'
cur.execute(st, l)
cur.fetchall()
```

Result:

```
((1, 1, 1000, 'Deposit'), (2, 1, 500, 'Fees'))
```

My question is, is this SQL statement parameterized well as safe from basic SQL injection?

Comment: You're using pymysql correctly. That's the best it can do. There's no MySQL connector for Python that implements real query parameters. They only copy values into the SQL query string before preparing it, and they do apply best-effort quoting and escaping to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: you could you mysql coonector https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/  for prepare3d stqaements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do PyMySQL prevent user from sql injection attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647301/how-do-pymysql-prevent-user-from-sql-injection-attack)