# Run SQL via command via Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm struggling to write this SQL query into a Python script.

All the variables are stored in Python.  I need the SQL statement to pass my python variables and then execute the query.

The SQL statement should query col1, col2, col3 in the DB for 'this_string', and then update field1, field2 and field3 with string1, string2, and string3.

But I can't figure it out..

```
mystring = 'this_string'
string1 = 'test1'
string2 = 'test2'
string3 = 'test3'

UPDATE databaseb.name SET field1 = string1, field2 = string2, field3 = string3 WHERE CONCAT_WS('', column1,column2,column3) LIKE '%this_string%'
```

I tried this

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "1.2.3.4",
user="me",
passwd="passwd",
db="dbname",
use_unicode=True,
charset="utf8")
x = conn.cursor()
x.execute(UPDATE databaseb.name SET field1 = string1, field2 = string2, field3 = string3 WHERE CONCAT_WS('', column1,column2,column3) LIKE '%this_string%'
)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be in quotes and it is a good practice to parameterize your sql. It could look something like this:

```
x.execute("""UPDATE databaseb.name SET field1 = %s, field2 = %s, field3 = %s WHERE CONCAT_WS('', column1,column2,column3) LIKE %s""",(string1, string2, string3, '%'+this_string+'%'))
```

Reference: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: I've gotten further with this, but it's not quite working.  Can you please explain this part a bit more?:     LIKE '%%%s%%'"""

Comment: It gives this error which shows the % isn't quite right:     Syntax error in your SQL syntax; near 'this_string'%'' at line 1"

Comment: Yes, the comment directly above seems to show the error:  'this_string'%  
  is what is being inserted into the query via the  %%%s%%  listed at top.  But what it needs to insert is:   '%this_string%'   .... I've tried to tinker with the %s thing, but I get errors.

Comment: Ok, well your edit fixes the issue.  But I still get a syntax error:  Syntax error in your SQL syntax near '%this_string%''' at line 1.     Any idea how I can get Python to print out what the SQL statement will look like with variables and all?

Comment: @user7433145 I fixed the query to remove the incorrect ticks around the search string. I would check out this answer to view the last query run (even queries run with exceptions) - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7190914/7016601)

Comment: Ok.. well no more errors... but the data isn't being written to the DB.

Comment: Nevermind.... I had an error in my CONCAT_WS and I was looking in the wrong column.  Your final solution works.   Thanks so much!!!

Comment: And for anyone else that stumbles upon this...  I used this:::   x = conn.cursor()        print x._executed     :::to see the SQL query within Python

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you are getting? If it is syntax error, it is because you didn't surround your UPDATE command in quotes (`"`).

I mean:

```
x.execute("UPDATE databaseb.name SET field1 = string1, field2 = string2, field3 = string3 WHERE CONCAT_WS('', column1,column2,column3) LIKE '%this_string%'")
```

Remember that `x.execure` is a function that receives a string object as input. This string should specify the SQL command to execute, but it a string nonetheless.