# How to debug 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Tags: python, mysql

There are several questions on `You have an error in your SQL syntax` - but they all seem to address a specific syntax error in the query, which is generally not helpful to others.

My question is how can I get the formatted query from a MySQL command in Python so that I can actually inspect it?

So I have a statement like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products(acc, title, sku, price, price_checked, desc, imgs) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (1, prod.title, prod.sku, prod.price, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), prod.desc, prod.imgs))
```

And the error is:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
>   ear 'desc, imgs) VALUES (1,'Holy Stone HS700 FPV Drone with 1080p HD Camera Live Vide' at line 1")

Any idea how I can get the executed query? I don't want to format the query myself then print it before executing, but rather use MySQL's built in formatting for security reasons, mainly.

Comment: Not sure what is your question. But if you want format the query  try http://dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm , if you want debug the query why dont test it on mysql directly?

Comment: That isn't the query that's throwing the error? It's talking about `desc` so presumably it's a SELECT query. This is an INSERT and doesn't include DESC

Comment: @roganjosh Yes it does include desc. It's the second last argument. Do you see it?

Comment: First try to surround the text data with quotes.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov Datetime too?

Comment: @User, i think so yes.

Answer (score 0):

`DESC` is a keyword in SQL for sorting in descending order. You can't call one of your parameters `"desc"` because it will be interpreted as such. Think about if you called one of your columns "Select"; it's the same issue. You need to rename that field.

Initially I was focused on `prod.desc` but in your query string, you have `'desc'` listed as an actual column name: `"... products(acc, title, sku, price, price_checked, desc, imgs)"`

You can see the last query run using the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7190914/4799172) but I can't test as I don't have any MySQL instance.

Comment: `prod` is an  object with `desc` property. That is pass to `%s` as parameter

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no, forget about the python object being passed (I saw that first too), they literally have a column called "desc"; `...INTO products(acc, title, sku, price, price_checked, desc, imgs)`

Comment: Thanks - this worked. Can you just add a method to view the query executed?

Comment: @User edited but can't test. It's not relevant to your issue anyway because you didn't spot that you were using a keyword and it's not flagging it as such in the error (explicitly, anyway).