# PYTHON/MySQL: Check if Record exist. If exist don't insert, if not exist then insert

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

First Check the website for link, then get all the links. 
I need help to the check the mysql, if the links is already there, if those exist then don't insert them, if some of them doesnt exist, then insert them.

```
  created_at = time.strftime("%Y/%d/%m/ %H:%M:%S")
afdelings = 'it-support'

url = 'www.careerjet.dk/sog/jobs?s=L%C3%A6rling&l=Danmark'
r  = requests.get("http://" +url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
side1 = "http://www.careerjet.dk/"
cur = connect.cursor()

for link in soup.select('.title > a'):
  linkfrom = side1 + (link.get('href'))
  f = string.split(linkfrom, '\n')
  for line in f:
    if ("""SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line)) == 0:
      cur.execute("""INSERT INTO jobtest (afdeling, dato, link) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (afdelings, created_at, line))

with connect:
  connect.commit()

connect.close()
```

please any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the select first.

Some thing like this

```
 created_at = time.strftime("%Y/%d/%m/ %H:%M:%S")
 afdelings = 'it-support'

 url = 'www.careerjet.dk/sog/jobs?s=L%C3%A6rling&l=Danmark'
 r  = requests.get("http://" +url)
 data = r.text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
 side1 = "http://www.careerjet.dk/"
 cur = connect.cursor()

 for link in soup.select('.title > a'):
   linkfrom = side1 + (link.get('href'))
   f = string.split(linkfrom, '\n')
   for line in f: 

     #-------ADDED CODE
     data_tmp = """SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line)
     data_tmp = cur.fetchall()
     #-------END ADDED CODE

     if (data_tmp == 0 ) :
       cur.execute("""INSERT INTO jobtest (afdeling, dato, link) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (afdelings, created_at, line))

 with connect:
   connect.commit()

 connect.close()
```

Comment: It came up with "NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined." Then I tried
with "cur.fetchall(data_tmp)" and it comes with the error:
"fetchall() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)".
Thanks for your help btw. Any chance you have idea about this?

Comment: Ok i put data_tmp = cur.execute("""SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line))
but still no data is inserted into the mysql.

Comment: Maybe because that link was already inserted based on your requirements. What is the result from `data_tmp` variable?

Comment: When i print "%s" % data_tmp:
I get (0L,)

Comment: Change `data_tmp = cursor.fetchall()` to `data_tmp = cur.fetchall()`

Comment: Already did that. but then i have to change data_tmp = """SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line)
to
data_tmp = cur.execute("""SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line))

Comment: I there any error showing? Please print cur.mogrify()

Comment: It doesn't come with any errors:
Where specific should i put it? I get; 
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'mogrify' i

Comment: Add this `print cur.mogrify()` after `cur.fetchall()` function and after `cur.execute`

Comment: data_tmp = cur.execute("""SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line))
     print cur.mogrify()
     data_tmp = cur.fetchall()
     print cur.mogrify()
like this?

I still get:
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'mogrify'

Do i need to add any library to do this?

Comment: Could it be, if there isnt anything in mysql that it can checkup on, thats the fault?

Comment: Oopps . I thought You are using postgres. Please see reference to see executed command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266430/how-to-see-the-real-sql-query-in-python-cursor-execute