# Cannot perform parameterized query with pyodbc

Tags: sql, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, 4d-database

I have this query working through ODBC to a 4D database. It returns records as expected.

```
with pyodbc.connect('dsn=datasource') as db4dcon:  
    print(db4dcon)
    db4dcur = db4dcon.cursor()
    print(db4dcur)
    db4dcur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sampling WHERE Id='2017-043';")
    print(db4dcur.rowcount)

<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x029CC068>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0292B058>
3
```

I would like to change it to a parameterized version, but I could not succeed. I have read the [doc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki#Parameters), and none of those example work for me.

Neither:

```
db4dcur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sampling WHERE Id=?;", '2017-043')
```

Nor:

```
db4dcur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sampling WHERE Id=?;", ('2017-043',))
```

Nor:

```
db4dcur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sampling WHERE Id=?;", ['2017-043']))
```

Work. They all lead to the following error:

```
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x02C7C068>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x028DB058>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 251, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "test.py", line 221, in main
    db4dcur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sampling WHERE Id=?;", '2017-043')
pyodbc.Error: ('08004', '[08004] Server rejected the connection:\nFailed to execute statement.\r (1110) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I have checked my ODBC connection, it seems server rejects a malformed query when replacing wildcard, but I cannot check what it is sent because of ODBC [mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5266430/7563009). Does anyone have an idea about what is going wrong with this parameterized query?

Comment: Your parameterized queries certainly look like they should work. Could you try using pypyodbc instead of pyodbc to see if it behaves any differently?

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I tried with pypyodbc and it works for each case.

Comment: It is interesting that pypyodbc works while pyodbc doesn't work - i would have suggested updating the ODBC driver or checking the ODBC TRACE LOG but i assume you are using the same query and same driver for both tests... Another option could be [P4D](https://github.com/ibrewster/p4d) which is a Python database module for the 4D database system using the native [SQLlib_4D](https://github.com/4D/SQLlib_4D) protocol.