# SQL Update with Variable as parameter error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I'v searched throughout this forum and couldn't find an answer.

```
cur.execute("UPDATE lastran SET job_date=newtimedate WHERE job_name=usrjobname")
```

Why is my code now working?

The two variables are newtimedate and usrjobname

Comment: is job_name a string/text type?  what error do you get?

Comment: what do you expect with "WHERE job_name=job_name"?

Comment: Updated post. The parameter is a variable.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Python, but it seems you're passing your variables as literals... a little Googling tells me this should be it?

```
cur.execute("UPDATE lastran SET job_date=? WHERE job_name=?", (newtimedate, usrjobname))
```

See how this person does it: [How to see the real SQL query in Python cursor.execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266430/how-to-see-the-real-sql-query-in-python-cursor-execute)